# Capturing a click event on all md-buttons with directive with Angular Material

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material as a UI framework in my AngularJS web application.

I am trying to perform a specific action on each `md-button` click. I assumed that it would just be as simple as adding a directive, although unfortunately nothing happens.

```
app.directive('md-button', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: function(scope, element){
            $(element).on('click', function (e) {
                console.log("button clicked");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

How can I perform an action on every `md-button` click on my site?

[EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/dMgdaM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your directive name using camelcase like this:

```
.directive('mdButton', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    link: function(scope, element){
        angular.element(element).on('click', function (e) {
            console.log("button clicked");
        });
    }
  };
});
```